# ¿Cómo convertir 2 variables de un data frame a un objeto POSIXct con formato "%Y%m%d %H%M%S"?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, date, dataframe, posix

Dado el dataset beaver1 (Body Temperature Series of Two Beavers)

```
data.frame':    114 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ day  : num  346 346 346 346 346 346 346 346 346 346 ...
 $ time : num  840 850 900 910 920 930 940 950 1000 1010 ...
 $ temp : num  36.3 36.3 36.4 36.4 36.5 ...
 $ activ: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

En donde

day.-es el Día de observación (desde principios de 1990)

time.- es la Hora de observación, en la forma 0330 para las 3:30 am

Quiero pasar las variables day y time a un objeto POSIXct para crear
un nuevo data frame "beaver" que contenga

```
 data.frame':   114 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ time : POSIXct, format "1990-12-12 08:40:00" "1990-12-12 08:50:00" "1990-12-12 09:00:00"   ...
 $ temp : num  36.3 36.3 36.4 36.4 36.5 ...
 $ activ: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

He intentado

```
as.POSIXct(paste(beaver1$day,beaver1$time), format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S", origin="1990-01-01 00:00:00)
```

pero resulta en:

```
    [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [27] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [53] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [79] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[105] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Creo que mi error está en format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S", origin="1990-01-01 00:00:00", pero no sé como corregirlo

El siguiente paso sería unir este nuevo objeto al data frame beaver1 para crear "beaver", sin embargo
estoy atorado en el paso anterior.

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida , gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`day` según se lee en la ayuda sería el número de día desde principios de 1990, por lo que podemos hacer a partir de un `POSIXct` ir sumándole los días llevados a segundos:

```
fecha <- as.POSIXct('1989-12-31', format='%Y-%m-%d') + (beaver1$day * 24*60*60)
```

Con `time` podemos simplemente descomponer el número tal cual está documentado en la ayuda, para llegar también a un número de segundos:

```
fecha <- fecha + 
         (beaver1$time %/% 100 + 24*(beaver1$day - beaver1$day[1]) + 
         (beaver1$time %% 100)/60)*3600
```

Finalmente:

```
> head(fecha)
[1] "1990-12-12 08:40:00 -02" "1990-12-12 08:50:00 -02" "1990-12-12 09:00:00 -02"
[4] "1990-12-12 09:10:00 -02" "1990-12-12 09:20:00 -02" "1990-12-12 09:30:00 -02"
```

Comment: Justo es lo que estaba buscando, gracias por tu ayuda.